# How to efficiently remove the 2 byte signature at the beginning of a 10mb log file and cat at same time

Tags: text-processing, scripting, cat

Ubuntu 16

I currently use cat to pipe a logfile from a remote machine to a website log viewer. The logfile has a two-byte signature at the beginning which tells it the file is 16bit or 8bit.

if I nano the file, the file looks like so ...

```
��2^@0^@1^@8^@0^@4^@2^@8^@ ^@1^@5^@:^@4^@3^@:^@0^@8^@
^@0^@1^@8^@0^@4^@2^@8^@ ^@1^@5^@:^@4^@3^@:^@0^@8^@
```

If I `cat filename` I can still see the first 2 bytes at the beginning of the file

```
▒▒20180428 15:43:08
20180428 15:43:08
```

If I do `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 filename` It looks great in shell ...

```
20180430 03:57:46
20180430 03:57:46
```

but shows up on the website with the first line partially encoded

```
20180430 03:57:46 ㋾　㄀㠀　㐀㌀　 　㌀㨀㔀㜀㨀㐀㘀 嘀攀爀猀椀漀渀           㴀 㐀⸀　⸀　਀
```

Now if I reverse the log `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 filename | tac` it shows up on the website perfectly.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your comment worked well with ```cat filename | tail -c +3``` and in reverse ```cat filename | tail -c +3 | tac ```.

Comment: I tried to upvote your comment, then I downvoted by mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Could you post a hexdump of the beginning of the file before and after your `iconv` conversion?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the first 2 bytes, you could try:

```
dd if=orginal_file of=new_file ibs=2 skip=1
```

That will output `new_file` with the first 2 bytes skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to remove the first two bytes you can do so with `tail -c +3`. For instance:

```
$ printf 'hello\n' >> file1
$ tail -c +3 file1
llo
$ _
```